# How to add private packages in azure ml environment?

Tags: pip, yaml, azure-pipelines, conda, azure-machine-learning-service

I have python script (train_pipeline.py) which creates and runs an azure ml pipeline. It uses environment.yml to create the conda environment. This works, except for one private library (utils) which is referenced in the yml file through it's relative path. When I create the conda environment locally, everything works as expected. However when azure ml creates the environment, it is not able to find the utils folder.

How can I include private packages to azure ml environment?

Directory structure:

```
| azure_pipelines
|--- train_pipeline.py
| projects
|--- project_1
|---|--- script.py
|---|--- environment.yml
| utils
|--- database_utils
|---|---__init__.py
|---|---connection.py
|--- setup.py
```

environment.yml content:

```
name: env_name
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pyodbc
  - pandas
  - pip:
    - azureml-core
    - ../../utils
prefix: /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/env_name
```

train_pipeline.py:

```
...
environment = Environment.from_conda_specification('env_name', '../projects/project_1/environment.yml')
...
```

Comment: Is it possible the relative path is using current working directory rather than relative to the YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a .whl file for your private package. You already have a "setup.py" file in your "utils" directory, so assuming it's correctly set up (you can take a look [here](https://www.realpythonproject.com/how-to-create-a-wheel-file-for-your-python-package-and-import-it-in-another-project/) if you're not sure), open the "utils" directory in the terminal and run the following instruction:

> python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal

This will create the wheel in a new "dist" directory under "utils". You can now add it to your environment:

```
whl_url = environment.add_private_pip_wheel(
    workspace = <Workspace object>,
    file_path = "../utils/dist/<wheel filename>"
)
environment.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package(whl_url)
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-private-python-packages) explain this last part fairly well.